# linux cn_proc proc_event value is strange

Tags: c++, linux, process, process-monitoring

Hello I'm testing netlink socket

I create netlink socket and receive process event data. it works well.

But I faced something weird situations.

Received proc event value was "3"

In linux cn_proc.h process events defined

[image]

there is only 0x1, 0x2, 0x4 not 3 in definitions...

So I guess process event value 3 is result of bit-wise operation

PROC_EVENT_FORK & PROC_EVENT_EXEC
( 0x 0000 0001  &  0x 0000 0002  )

But I can't find any reference for proving my theory

Is there any knows about this issue?

Regards

Thanks

Comment: it's `PROC_EVENT_FORK | PROC_EVENT_EXEC` not `&`. Could be piece wise constructed like `what |= PROC_EVENT_EXEC;`. Also the comment in your screenshot itself says "Use successive bits so the enums can be used to record sets of events as well"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't read comments and trying to translate it.